# how to set QTWEBKIT_PLUGIN_PATH

Tags: linux, flash, webkit, gtk

On the Linux platform, WebKit can set the environment variable QTWEBKIT_PLUGIN_PATH to set the location of the Flash plug-in program to read *. So file in the directory.And I want to know how to set  QTWEBKIT_PLUGIN_PATH??

Answer (score 0):

from shell 
export QTWEBKIT_PLUGIN_PATH="/home/xyz..." replace xyz  with your directory of plugins

Comment: Thank you very much!I was successful!